# How to get the Average Duration when having start & end month

Tags: node.js

i am currently trying to gather some "stats" for my users.

I am using NodeJs for backend, via Socket.io, data is saved to MongoDB

I have a "Start Month" and a "End Month"
which determines When the user has started, and when the user' session is ended.

The time is stored in unix

How would i manage to solve this? i am currently trying to move forward using this line

activeTreatmentDuration = (maxDate - minDate) / 25920000;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When manipulating dates I like to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). I has a really nice API, with a rigourous documentation.

It is unclear from your question what stat you are trying to obtain but with moment is it easy for example:

- to format a time diff:

```
    moment.duration(moment(endMonth).diff(moment(startMonth))).humanize();
```

- to get the value of a date or a duration in any time unit:

```
    moment.duration(moment(endMonth).diff(moment(startMonth))).get('month');
```

etc..

Comment: Thanks pal, ended up using moment.duration(moment(maxDate).diff(moment(minDate))).asMonths();